# Can we open .exe file in browser from server?

Tags: java, javascript, applet

Please help me if this is possible to do.  I am having **.EXE**  file on server i want to run that file in web browser.

Please guide me how can i implement this?

Comment: No, you can't. EXE is a desktop application and cannot run on browser

Comment: Here is something similar you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152482/running-exe-from-javascript

Answer (score 1):

Web browsers cannot natively execute a random .EXE file (imagine the security implications).

Having said that, on a Windows machine (example), using ActiveX (in the IE browser for the sake of example) or the Mime handling capabilities of the browser, you can open up a Excel spreadsheet, PDF, even invoke Outlook (etc.) on your PC. This assumes the user have allowed such execution to occur etc... But its not the same as running the .EXE

Comment: *"on a Windows machine, ActiveX can be used to open up a Excel spreadsheet, PDF, even invoke Outlook (etc.) on your PC."*  Not in FF, or Chrome, or..

Comment: @AndrewThompson you can definitely open up a PDF via Chrome. My meaning is imply (a) you just can't run a .EXE, (b) it is possible however in some cases for a file to be opened such as PDF/Spreadsheet/Mail via the capabilities of the browser. Not wanting to start a comment war, thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to open a `.exe` file in the browser.  Internet Explorer can open ActiveX controls, and browsers with Java can load applets, but nether is a Windows executable file like you seem to want.

Comment: Other browsers can run `.exe` files using emulators like [Boxedwine](http://www.boxedwine.org/), even if they don't support ActiveX.