# Launch desktop App from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php

Hello to all friends and thanks in advance.

my web-base app need open server side file into `client-side desktop` default app associated office document file ,like `Do`c and `Docx` file are open in `MS OFFICE` , `PDF` file are open in `ADOBE READER` OR `NITRO`, ETC...

I do lot of google and find some solution like `activeXObject` (not much full control)
[Running .exe from Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152482/running-exe-from-javascript)
but that solution scope limited to `IE-Explorer`. I need that feature (opening DOCUMENT FILE by DESKTOP APP) in all browser.

my app current build in PHP Version 5.5.9, PHP provide COM and DOTNET it work smoothly but its server side (any solution to send them client side).

or may be I handle or proceed that problem in wrong way if any kind of feature are possoble??

Comment: I think you can't do this with crome

Comment: The client browser will do that work for you. Just provide the link and serve the content with the appropiate content-type.

You can't (and you shouldn't) control the actual opening of the file, beyond the browser behaviour. The browser recognizes and honors the user preferences.