# I can't open an exe using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, asp-classic, activex

I just want to open a notepade.exe using html Js ,I tried this code but its not working Can any one help me over this. This file is run.html !!!

```
<html>
  <head>
   <script>
    alert("hi");
    <!-- myWindow.close();   -->
    var param1var = window.location.search.replace( "?", "" );
    alert(param1var);
    var oShell = new ActiveXObject("Shell.Application");
    var commandtoRun = "C:\\Windows\\notepad.exe"; 
    oShell.ShellExecute(commandtoRun,"","","open","1");
    window.close()
   </script>
  </head>
</html>
```

Comment: Define "it's not working". What happens? Do you get an error?

Comment: Possible duplicate with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152482/running-exe-from-javascript

Comment: I just used notepad and can see an error in console says "Uncaught ReferenceError: ActiveXObject is not defined "

Comment: @VigneshMarteen Are you trying to run this code in Internet Explorer? ActiveXObject can be used only in IE.

Comment: hi Dean.DePue, I tried the same link and copied the output and pasted it here. Even though its not running.

Comment: @Gergo Erdose, I tried running it in internet explorer i get an error saying that "SCRIPT70: Permission deniedFile: run.html, Line: 10, Column: 1" in console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open Internet Explorer and change / enable these two settings

`Tools > Internet Options > Security > Custom level > ActiveX Controls and plug-ins > Initialize and script ActiveX controls not marked as safe for scripting`

`Tools > Internet Options > Advanced > Security > Allow Active Content to run in files on My Computer`

Just in case, restart Internet Explorer