# Is it possible to run an .exe file within Internet Explorer 11?

Tags: internet-explorer, activex, windows-8.1, internet-explorer-11

The OS is Windows 8.1 - I am wondering if it is possible to install an ActiveX based wrapper to run an .exe file within the IE11 window. It would be ideal if it can be launched via a link on a webpage.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is possible via javascript. Here's an example to a working solution:

[Running .exe from Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152482/running-exe-from-javascript)

In your case, you just need to make those lines of code a function and then create a hyperlink:

```
var executeShell = function(){
    var oShell = new ActiveXObject("Shell.Application");
    var commandtoRun = "C:\\Windows\\notepad.exe"; 
    oShell.ShellExecute(commandtoRun,"","","open","1");
};


<a href="#execute" onclick="executeShell();return false;">Run an exe</a>
```