# Signal from browser to desktop application

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, web

How then problem of sending signals (on some events) from web-site to desktop application (written on C#) can be solved? Which approaches you can recommend? Is WebSocket protocol is good for these goals?

Comment: Do you mean something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152482/running-exe-from-javascript

Comment: I'd recommend doing some research into it and trying something yourself, first.  We can help when you have some code with issues.

Comment: try https://www.asp.net/signalr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Websockets from Javascript in HTML or poll the website for data using a HttpRequest object in C#.

I would recommend polling for data via HttpRequest since the data will be a little more reliable when not generated completely on the client machine.

Also you may use encryption methods for security.

Comment: If you're considering using Websockets, then look at http://asp.net/signalr which wraps this for you in the latest tech with fallbacks.

Comment: @Bastian von Halem, Thank you!