# How browser asks to open an application?

Tags: javascript, browser, process

How does the browser ask to open a particular application like this? Did it know this application is installed on my computer?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKZAZ.png)

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3152482/15781079) may answer your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the browser does not know whether or not you have the application that is shown, the browser is programmed, in case a protocol url (such as "steam://", "roblox://" among others) is opened, it does it with this box is shown, when an app is installed, for example, Roblox, when you install it, it installs together, a URL Protocol, which serves to run the program.