# Django launch windows app from website Django?

Tags: python, django, django-views

in an application, I want to open the zoom application on the user's computer from my website, how can I do this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are usung Djongo Rest for your application integrated with a Javascript -framework front end i would suggest you look at the following answer detailing the solution for a Javascript based framework.
[Running .exe from Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152482/running-exe-from-javascript).
If not maybe you could add more details to your questions, like are you running a Django CMS aplication?

Comment: İm using https://riot-api-libraries.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lcu.html ,  this api run just 
user localhost, iwant  connect user pc and run localhost

Comment: I am still not sure i understand you. This library just goes through some basics API. I would suggest trying to better re-express your question. If you want just to open an .exe file by clicking on a button , the previous function details how you can do it via a Javascript function. Otherwise it would not make sense to launch an .exe file server side.

Comment: İ deploy my website heroku  
İ want to get request user localhost but i run this script get request running heroku server localhost