# Running other Unity executables on runtime

Tags: unity-game-engine, build, exe, unity-webgl

I am trying to make CV/portfolio-ish game with WebGL build and I want to show people my previous games.

I wonder if there is anyway to run my previous games exes on WebGL at runtime. Like game inside game but I don't want to move all of the assets, codes etc. Opening extra web page with WebGL is an option but I want to try my question first.

Thanks.

Comment: Other page with WebGL I would say .. there is no way to run an `exe` afaik (except [it already exists on the target device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152482/running-exe-from-javascript) .. but again this was 10 years ago ^^) .. WebGL should be pretty sandboxed ... you can of course as well provide some downloads .. but who will just download and execute some random `exe` file from the internet ;)

Comment: Yeah external download is not an option at this situation but thanks for fast response.