# Start a process on client pc from mvc web application

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

Can any one help me?

I have copied a exe from server to client pc.

```
System.IO.File.Copy(Server.MapPath(@"\BrowserPlugin.exe"), localPath + "BrowserPlugin.exe", true);
```

Now i want to start this exe on client side.

```
var psi = new ProcessStartInfo();    
psi.CreateNoWindow = true;    
psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;    
psi.FileName = localPath + "BrowserPlugin.exe";     
psi.UseShellExecute = false;    
Process.Start(psi);
```

but unable to start this process.

it returns  `ExitCode: 255`

Comment: You can't just do that. Thats a huge security risk. Put it on a file share and add a link to it or use ClickOnce.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to launch an EXE from Web page (asp.net)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/916925/how-to-launch-an-exe-from-web-page-asp-net)