# How can we open Google chorme window on server triggred through webservice?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, selenium, window

I am trying to open google chrome window on remote server through a webservice deployed on same server. The `chrome` is opening I can see process in `Task Manager` but unable to see the chrome window when I login.

Is it possible to see `chrome window` as well? I am using below code in the `webservice`.

```
public string openChrome()
{
    Process.Start(@"chrome.exe");
    return "Hello World";
}
```

Comment: its not possible because the asp.net is running under their account / different than yours.

Comment: @Aristos it possible with any other way? Like creating a window service or anyting?

Comment: no its not possible, especial services have no user interface that chrome requires to run. I do not think that you can do what you try to do, to see what chrome loads and runs from another acount

Answer (score 0):

Read [How to launch an EXE from Web page (asp.net)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/916925/how-to-launch-an-exe-from-web-page-asp-net) or [this](https://weblogs.asp.net/morteza/How-to-run-a-desktop-application-from-a-web-page). However the most straightforward way would be to create a small desktop listener that you could run under your account and that would query the webservice, etc. from time to time (e.g. every 1 min) and launch the required command.

Comment: awesome mate !!