# How can I run exe application in a web page (HTML FILE),to be launched in the web page?

Tags: exe, html

I have developed and exe application and i need to upload to be used online how can import exe application to be run in a web page.
thank you.

Comment: the short answer - without your users downloading and installing a 3rd party application prior to using your site, you can't. might wana take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/916925/how-to-launch-an-exe-from-web-page-asp-net

Answer (score 0):

https://turbo.net/studio

After installing  browser-plugin you can run prepared applications normally written for desktop-usage on the web in a sandbox.