# How do I open a program that is installed on the desktop from a web page?

Tags: javascript

someone knows how to open a program that is installed on the desktop from a web page, something like the onedrive option where from the web you can tell them to open a document and open word with that document or like when you open a torrent link  ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to launch an EXE from Web page (asp.net)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/916925/how-to-launch-an-exe-from-web-page-asp-net)

Comment: @RakeshNair: No, it is not. This poster is asking about opening files that are on the web in the associated application (in a way similar to how Word or PDF files are opened), not launching a random executable.

Answer (score 1):

You basically have to download a file that is recognized by the program you wish to start. That program has to be pre-installed on the machine. The file should include instructions the program understand, and can execute.

In any case, this is quite fragile, and depends on many variables you have little control over, including the user, who might decline the download, or just save the file without opening it. So you should try a different approach to achieve what you want, than running a program on a user's computer.